# Separating columns into multiple columns excel2010

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

What I need to do: 
I have two columns in excel, (x) and (y) essentially
There are multiple data sets continuing down columns A & B (it ranges, but the one I've been working on goes down to about ~80,000 and has roughly 8 data sets; the full data set would be much longer)

**Screen Shot of what the data looks like here:

[image]

The values continue for about 200 cells, where the header (image name, image plane, etc) repeats, and the next plane's X and Y values are listed.

**Screen shot of what I want it to look like here:

[image]

**I've started to write the code with a "Do Until" loop but get stuck with how I can assign the stop to be at a cell either with text or with "Image Name" as the content. Either would work.

I wanted to get this figured out before I move on to reading the next image data sets and pasting each set three columns apart on Sheet 2 (see screen shot of what I want it to look like).

What I've written so far (and I know it's rather lacking because I'm struggling with parts of VBA to learn it):

```
Sub Test2()  
    ' Test2 Macro  
    ' Automating  

    Dim X As Text Set X:= "Image Name"  

    'Select cell A2, *first line of data*  
    Range("A2").Select   
    'Set Do loop to stop when end of selection is reached   
    Do Until X(ActiveCell)  
        Selection.Copy  
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select  
        ActiveSheet.Paste  
        ' Step down 1 row from present location  
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Seclect Loop  
End Sub
```

I've been able to better understand some of the functions, but I'm still missing how to assign a variable. For instance, to make X equal the string "Image Name" and set Do until X so that the function of the Do loop works until it hits the "image name" cell content (or until it hits text, either would work.)

Thanks a bunch for any suggestions! I'll still be working on this and trying to get it right so I'll update the code if I have anything more to add.

Comment: It's really hard to understand what your data looks like, as you can imagine. Could you maybe do a screenshot and post to imgur.com or a similar image sharing site. Someone with enough points can put the picture in your post. Also, have you tried writing any VBA to solve this problem yet? It sounds like VBA will probably be the way to go since the data is so complex.

Comment: Few things you should consider. As mentioned, VBA. Use the split function like this: varArray = split(whatever,",") will split up a comma seperated string into an array.

Comment: Few things you should consider. As mentioned, VBA. Use the split function like this: varArray = split(whatever,",") will split up a comma seperated string into an array. Also, data->text to cols. if you have a properly organised data set, this is the easiest way to split them up. But it sounds like maybe you need to work on the data format a bit first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of information, but at the end of your post you state you need to assign a variable.

First we need to declare a variable. You are attempting to declare `x` as text. Text isn't a data type in VBA, so we'll use `String`.

```
Dim x as String
```

Now we need to assign `x` a value. Here are 2 examples

```
x = "assigned value"  'assigned by hard-coding the value
x = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value  'assigned by using the value of A1 on Sheet2
```

Now you've got some other issues in your code (pasting without copying, started a Do loop without closing it), but you'll need to specifically ask where you need help.

Comment: Thanks @guitarthrower that's just what I needed! I know I asked for more initially, it was more of a "I'm stuck on assigning a variable" and if I got help with that I think I can figure the rest of it out, but if someone had a suggestion for going about the code in a better way then I'd appreciate that as well.

Comment: Glad I could help. This site works best with specific questions. When things get broad, it's more difficult to answer questions. Welcome to SO, and post other questions as you get stuck.